# Does a Java manifest have a defined/conventional set of attributes?

Tags: java

When creating a manifest file in a jar you can put in any key-value pairs as long as they don't break length or character requirements.

Are there any conventions on the items that are commonly in manifests though?
Names/ordering etc?

e.g. `Implementation-Title` and `Implementation-Version` seem pretty standard.
A build date also seems quite common but is there a convention for it? e.g. `Build-Date` vs `Build-Timestamp`?

I'm building it by hand in this case, so the reason for this question is that I'm wondering if any build tool (like Maven for instance) has set any conventions in the same way that the convention of `src/main/java` has come about.

Comment: The [specification for jarfiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes) covers quite a few example attributes, though the link provided is for Java 7.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable answer